# set a new id for a class in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a class as

```
 <div class="group-left article_left">
```

I need to add a id for this class dynamically using JavaScript.

i have added the following code

```
    var thediv = document.getElementByClass("#group-left");
     thediv.id = "pad_id";
```

But the id is not appearing in my code.Can anyone help me.

Comment: Did you mean something like `document.getElementsByClassName('group-left')[0]`?

Comment: Yeah, remember the pound sign '#' is used for id's. Also remember that id's are supposed to be unique. You may run into some weird issues if you repeat your id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now getElementsByClass method in javascript unless you use some library. You can use jquery

```
$('.class').attr('id','pad_id');
```

You should only use one id per element though. Remember that

Comment: [There is if you spell it right.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname)

Answer (score 1):

The method is called `getElementsByClassName` and returns a NodeList, not a single node (so you need to treat it as an array and either loop over it or just grab the first element from it).

You also need to spell your class name correctly. You don't have a `#` character in it.

```
 var thediv = document.getElementsByClassName("group-left")[0];
 thediv.id = "pad_id";
```

It [isn't supported by Internet Explorer 8 or lower](http://caniuse.com/#search=getElementsByClassName) so you may wish to use a polyfill or a library (such as YUI or anything else implementing [a selector engine](http://microjs.com/#css)) with equivalent functionality instead.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `setAttribute`, like such:

```
thediv.setAttribute("id", "pad_id");
```

Comment: No, the `id` property works just fine … if you use it on an HTMLElementNode instead of `undefined`